# How to align content inside of a component in Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this image:

[image: e]

As you can see, there are four transparent buttons inside of it, Home, Offers, About and Contact.

How can I align them to the bottom of the image instead of the top?

Here is my code:

```
<v-img src="@/assets/banner/webbanner.png">
  <v-container>
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-btn
        color="transparent"
        class="mx-2 white--text"
        depressed
        width="200"
        v-for="(button, index) in viewButtons"
        :key="index"
      >
        {{ button.name }}
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-img>
```

Comment: add this to your component styles: `.container{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px
}`

Comment: Thank you! You could post it as an answer and I'll checkmark it so that it's easier to see to people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify v-container styles by accessing its [`staticClass: 'container'`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ad1f6ce8cf5261b60665222b2854615bcef7c2f3/packages/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/VContainer.ts#L55)

So just add

```
<v-container class="container-scoped">...</...>
.container-scoped{ position: absolute; bottom: 0px }
```

to your component styles.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-img
        src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/500/300"
        lazy-src="https://picsum.photos/id/11/10/6"
        aspect-ratio="1"
        class="grey lighten-2"
        max-width="250"
        max-height="150"
      >
        <v-container
          style="position:absolute;bottom:0px"
          
        >
          <v-row align="center" justify="space-around">
            <div class="white--text mx-2">btn</div>
            <div class="white--text mx-2">btn</div>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-img>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this suggested. You are much better to use a framework, and stay away from hardcoded 0px, and also position absolute in this instance isn't in any way flexible when resizing and different monitor sizes. ALSO overriding the default container is not good practice.

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly I agree that overriding the default container class is bad practice - but i dont understand your hardcoded issue? this is within `.v_responsive` -> relative and thus trapped within `v-img` default slot.

Comment: Your suggested edit was very nice. Thanks :) and agreed. I could have used the framework better, but i wanted to quickly help this man on his way.

Comment: It is not a good idea override styles on vuetify, use helpers instead

Comment: @FernandoTorres my favorite one is `html {overflow-y:hidden}` ;)  but yes - agreed on is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

I would pull the container out of the v-imge. and then give it a flex class

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
  <v-img src="@/assets/banner/webbanner.png" class="imageContent" />
  <v-container>
    <v-row" justify="space-between">
      <v-btn
        color="transparent"
        class="mx-2 white--text"
        depressed
        width="200"
        v-for="(button, index) in viewButtons"
        :key="index"
      >
        {{ button.name }}
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

I hven't tested this, but flexbox will help a lot https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

it should get you started and pointed in the right direction.